# Issue attempting to write bUnit Test for MudBlazor (error rendering MudPopover)

Tags: mudblazor, bunit

I am currently attempting to write some unit tests using bUnit. The component, I'm rendering is failing due to an error related to the MudPopover. So I've identified the issue is when it tries to implement/leverage that component as seen below.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MudBlazor
  StackTrace:
   at MudBlazor.MudPopover.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception& renderFragmentException)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Bunit.Rendering.TestRenderer.AssertNoUnhandledExceptions()
   at Bunit.Rendering.TestRenderer.Render[TResult](RenderFragment renderFragment, Func`2 activator)
   at Bunit.Rendering.TestRenderer.RenderFragment(RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Bunit.Extensions.TestContextBaseRenderExtensions.RenderInsideRenderTree(TestContextBase testContext, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Bunit.Extensions.TestContextBaseRenderExtensions.RenderInsideRenderTree[TComponent](TestContextBase testContext, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Bunit.TestContext.Render[TComponent](RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Bunit.TestContext.RenderComponent[TComponent](Action`1 parameterBuilder)
```

I've then decided to try and take a step back and just use those components - just to see how they should load (code below) but get the same error. Can someone advise the proper way to either Mock or initialize the MudPopover for bUnit tests?

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestRender()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        using var context = new TestContext();
        services.AddMudServices();
        services.AddSingleton<MudPopoverProvider>();
        var mudPop = new Mock<MudPopover>();
        var mudPoperProvider = new Mock<MudPopoverProvider>();
        var mudPopService = new Mock<IMudPopoverService>();

        mudPop.Setup(m => m.SetParametersAsync(new ParameterView())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
        context.Services.AddSingleton(mudPoperProvider.Object);
        context.Services.AddSingleton(mudPop.Object);
        context.Services.AddSingleton(mudPopService.Object);


        context.RenderComponent<MudPopoverProvider>();
        context.RenderComponent<MudPopover>();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In my custom context that extends the bUnit TestContext I was able to get past this error with a bit of registration:

```
 Services.AddMudServices();
 JSInterop.SetupVoid("mudPopover.connect", _ => true);
```